# Saving Data from multiple android activity under one child in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and firebase. Making an android app for my final year project. I want to save the location of the user under the username under the BusinessOwner field. I want to save the location of the user when signing in. Your help will be really appreciated

[I have my firebase database like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dONF0.jpg)

[I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCl05.jpg)

**BusinessOwnerRegister.java**

```
package com.example.android.onroadsupport;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class BusinessOwnerRegister extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables
    TextInputLayout regName, regUsername, regEmail, regPhoneNo, regPassword,regFullAddress,regLandmark,regPinCode,regVoterID,regServiceType;
    Button regBtn;

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_owner_register);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Hooks to all xml elements in activity_user_register.xml
        regName = findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
        regUsername = findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        regEmail = findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        regPhoneNo = findViewById(R.id.reg_phoneNumber);
        regPassword = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        regBtn = findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
        regFullAddress = findViewById(R.id.reg_address);
        regLandmark = findViewById(R.id.reg_landmark);
        regPinCode = findViewById(R.id.reg_pinCode);
        regVoterID = findViewById(R.id.reg_voterID);
        regServiceType = findViewById(R.id.reg_serviceType);


    }


    private Boolean validateName() {
        String val = regName.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regName.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regName.setError(null);
            regName.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validateUsername() {
        String val = regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String noWhiteSpace = "\\A\\w{4,20}\\z";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regUsername.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (val.length() >= 15) {
            regUsername.setError("Username too long");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(noWhiteSpace)) {
            regUsername.setError("White Spaces are not allowed");
            return false;
        } else {
            regUsername.setError(null);
            regUsername.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validateEmail() {
        String val = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regEmail.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(emailPattern)) {
            regEmail.setError("Invalid email address");
            return false;
        } else {
            regEmail.setError(null);
            regEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validatePhoneNo() {
        String val = regPhoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regPhoneNo.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regPhoneNo.setError(null);
            regPhoneNo.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validatePassword() {
        String val = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String passwordVal = "^" +
                //"(?=.*[0-9])" +         //at least 1 digit
                //"(?=.*[a-z])" +         //at least 1 lower case letter
                //"(?=.*[A-Z])" +         //at least 1 upper case letter
                "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +      //any letter
                "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" +    //at least 1 special character
                "(?=\\S+$)" +           //no white spaces
                ".{4,}" +               //at least 4 characters
                "$";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regPassword.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(passwordVal)) {
            regPassword.setError("Password is too weak");
            return false;
        } else {
            regPassword.setError(null);
            regPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validateFullAddress() {
        String val = regFullAddress.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regFullAddress.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regFullAddress.setError(null);
            regFullAddress.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validateLandmark() {
        String val = regLandmark.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regLandmark.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regLandmark.setError(null);
            regLandmark.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validatePinCode() {
        String val = regPinCode.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regPinCode.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regPinCode.setError(null);
            regPinCode.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validateVoterID()  {
        String val = regVoterID.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regVoterID.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regVoterID.setError(null);
            regVoterID.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validateServiceType() {
        String val = regServiceType.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regServiceType.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            regServiceType.setError(null);
            regServiceType.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //This function will execute when user click on Sign up Button
    public void registerBusinessOwner(View view) {

        //Save data in firebase on button click
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("BusinessOwners");

        if (!validateName() | !validateUsername() | !validateEmail() | !validatePhoneNo() | !validatePassword() |
                !validateFullAddress() | !validateLandmark() | !validatePinCode() | !validateVoterID() | !validateServiceType()) {
            return;
        }


        //Get all the values in Strings
        String name = regName.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String username = regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String email = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String phoneNo = regPhoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String password = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String fullAddress = regFullAddress.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String landmark = regLandmark.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String pinCode = regPinCode.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String voterID = regVoterID.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String serviceType = regServiceType.getEditText().getText().toString();




        //Storing data in Firebase
        MechanicHelperClass mechanicHelperClass = new MechanicHelperClass(name, username, email, phoneNo, password, fullAddress, landmark, pinCode, voterID, serviceType);
        //Adding multiple users
        //Adding username as unique ID
        reference.child(username).setValue(mechanicHelperClass);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Account has been Created Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //Calling Login screen after Sign up completed
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.onroadsupport;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.audiofx.BassBoost;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.example.android.onroadsupport.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    Button callLogin;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2000;
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private boolean isPermission;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        //Call login from map
        callLogin = findViewById(R.id.callLoginFromMap);
        callLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, BusinessOwnerLogin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        if (requestSinglePermission()) {
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            mLocationManager  =(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            checkLocation();
        }


    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {

        if (!isLocationEnabled()){
            showAlert();
        }
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your location setting is set to off \n Please enable location to" + "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private boolean requestSinglePermission() {

        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        isPermission = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    //Check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            isPermission = false;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                    }
                }).check();
        return isPermission;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

       if (latLng!=null){

           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You"));
           mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,14f));
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL).setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient
                ,mLocationRequest,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

        String msg = "Updated Location : " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper(
                location.getLongitude(),
                location.getLatitude()
        );



        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BusinessOwners").child("Current Location")
                .setValue(locationHelper).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600 (six hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.